# Calling class library I get the error system.data.sqlclient is not supported on this platform

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, system.data.sqlclient

Here is the setup when I am getting this error:

Project "main" based on Core 3.1 and of type console application. Does not have a reference to System.Data.SqlClient and does not need one.

It calls project "process" also based on Core 3.1 of type class library. Does not have a reference to System.Data.SqlClient and does not need one.

"Process" calls project "service" based on Core 3.1 of type class library. This project needs System.Data.SqlClient and has a reference to a package "System.Data.SqlClient (4.5.1)".

When debugging "main", when it gets to "service", the first time it reference SqlConnection, it errors with message "system.data.sqlclient is not supported on this platform"

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it.

Note: When I add a refernce to System.Data.SqlClient in project "main" - no error, but of course as "main" does not need System.Data.SqlClient, it should not have one.

When I test "service" using xUnit, no errors, it works OK

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the [document](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#11-why-do-i-get-a-platformnotsupported-exception-when-my-application-hits-a-sqlclient-method):

> The Microsoft.Data.SqlClient NuGet package includes a number of DLLs
> supporting different .NET targets and different runtime platforms. If
> you are getting a PlatformNotSupported Exception when you don't think
> you should be, it ultimately means your application is not loading the
> appropriate DLL. There could be a number of reasons for this. The
> NuGet package structure and infrastructure around referencing and
> loading referenced NuGet packages includes logic that allows a package
> to contain multiple DLLs which implement support for different .NET
> and platform targets. Meaning a different DLL for .NET Framework, .NET
> Core, .NET Standard, Windows, Linux, etc. The NuGet infrastructure
> will automatically reference and load the appropriate DLL based on
> your application's needs.
>
> If your application loads a DLL from a NuGet package directly, it
> bypasses all this logic and probably loads the incorrect DLL. The DLL
> in the NuGet package under
> lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll is basically the
> fallback DLL for any unsupported target and simply throws the
> PlatformNotSupported exception for any call. This is a nicer exception
> than what you would otherwise get when running on a platform that does
> not have a DLL built for it. Ultimately, you want to use the NuGet
> package reference infrastructure or you would have to implement all
> this target framework and platform support logic yourself when
> determining which DLL to load.
>
> Additionally, the NuGet package contains all the dependency
> information for the SqlClient library and facilitates the downloading
> and referencing of dependencies. If you reference and load an
> individual DLL manually, it is up to you to ensure all dependencies
> are also available to the SqlClient library.

I suggest you could try to use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient instead. More details about cheat sheet for porting from System.Data.SqlClient to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, you could refer to this [article](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/blob/main/porting-cheat-sheet.md).

Comment: Thank you Brando.
Do you know why using Microsoft... can resolve the issue?
I did use the Package manager to add the System.Data.SqlClient and based on this document it should have worked properly but it did not. Meaning, it raised the error I mentioned in my questions.

Comment: Since the `System.Data.SqlClient` is written based on the .net framework, you could try to use  Microsoft.Data.SqlClient to test if this will work or not.